# meaning of 'operator' in this C++ statement

Tags: c++

What does the 'operator' mean in this C++ usage?

```
char* pszVar= W2A(_bstr_t(bstrVar).operator wchar_t*());
```

Comment: You can think of `operator wchar_t*` as a name of member function.

Answer (score 5):

forcing the compiler to choose the, apparently defined, "convert to wchar_t*" operator in that class. 
"that class" being whatever is returned from the _bstr_t call.

Answer (score 4):

That's an explicit call to the convertion operator to `wchar_t`, to be sure it's this one that will be used and not another.

That said, that's ugly and certainly show a problem in the class members.

Answer (score 3):

It marks an explicit call to the conversion operator to `wchar_t*`.

Comment: it is _not_ an operator, it is a construction for calling the conversion operator explicitly (as Klaim also answers).

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the the casting operator.